# Extracting a PE32 Windows executable archive in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, zip, 7-zip, archiving

Is it possible to extract a password protected Windows executable (.exe) in Linux?

This is the file's type:

```
file.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

Comment: Try to be more specific. How do you know it's a self-extracting (SFX) archive? Do you perhaps already know the type (7zip, WinRAR, WinZIP, …)? Have you considered Wine?

Comment: @DanielB I have executed it on Windows and entered the required password. I think it's WinRAR but I'm not sure if I remember correctly. I need a Linux solution other than Wine.

Comment: So, since you have tagged it _7-zip_, did you try using the `7z` command line utility yet?